# referencing a file as configmap in k8s

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-secrets

Alright, so I have a json file with google cloud credentials.
I want to add it to my cluster as a secret so right now I have this

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: google-credentials
stringData:
  credentials.json: |-
    <GOOGLE-CREDENTIALS>
```

And I am doing some sed hacks to try and get it to look right, but I am having tons of issues with it.

So I wonder: is it possible to reference a external file in your deployment.yaml?

And to be clear I have found out that I could do this

```
kubectl create configmap game-config --from-file=configure-pod-container/configmap/
```

But I would *strongly* prefer it to be in one command, i.e. `kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml`

Answer (score 0):

You can create the **configmap** or **secret** storing the whole file inside and you can inject it to **deployment**.

if you have issue with multiple command you can merge the YAML files simply by `---` so in single file your configmap will be there and deployment also.

You can apply this YAML file and your both resources will get created.

Something like :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: mock
spec:
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mock
spec:
```

Read more at : https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#create-configmaps-from-files

**OR**

> So I wonder: is it possible to reference a external file in your
> deployment.yaml?

If you have concerns merging files & creating **configmap**, if your file is external

you can create the Init container into deployment which will run before the main container start and set the file at its place.

If you **don't** want an **init container** also you can run **command** into **deployment** which will first download a file from a bucket of external place.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/